# How to find, read, write Jython registry during runtime

Tags: imagej, jython-2.7

I am using Jython as a macro language in ImageJ environment. I want to access private and protected fucntions. For this there is a Jython registry entry. I can't find the registry file. Jython runs within macro programming environment of ImageJ. I was wondering, if there is any way to get the path and entries of the current registry file within Jython code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the Jython Registry](https://www.jython.org/registry.html) lists, among others, the following source for the registry file:

> The user’s personal registry file, which contains similarly formated
> prop/value pairs. The user’s registry file is at `"user.home"+"/.jython"`

With a file `.jython` in your user home directory, containing the single line:

```
python.security.respectJavaAccessibility=false
```

... the following example script will output `1` without throwing an error:

```py
from ij import ImagePlus

print (ImagePlus.CLOSED) # a private field
```

---

Note that ImageJ-specific questions are best asked on the dedicated forum: https://forum.image.sc/tag/imagej

Comment: I read the documentation and I thought there should be a file already. Due to the isolated nature of ImageJ I thought this was hidden somewhere or completely missing.